# Override private method in superclass - is there a way?

Tags: java, inheritance

I know that the method would be protected not private if what I want to do was intended, however I want to make my own `PriorityQueue` that will need to call `siftUp` a few more times. I can't edit the declaration of the field as `PriorityQueue` is a part of the java library, so I'm looking for another way to call it. Is the only thing I can do copy the whole class from the library and change it to my needs?

Comment: What property are you talking about? You can override `offer(E e)` method and write your own `siftUp` implementation

Comment: @SunilChakravarthy sorry I meant declaration. Also yeah, that would work, however considering that I only need to call it more often, that seems like a lot of work. But better than copying the whole class, so thanks!

Comment: You can't override a private method (which is a good thing).  Otherwise, it wouldn't really be private.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to override the superclass's private method, unfortunately.

According to [Oracle's documentation on Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), the private method is only for the class itself to access.

Here's the table of the Superclass's visibility to Subclass:

[image: Superclass and subclass]

[image: Superclass's member visibility to subclass]

I believe they offer the developers to implement the "least privilege" principle by offering the **private** visibility so there would be no way for it to be accessible anywhere outside the class it was created in.

If you wanted to be able to override it, you should make it **protected** or don't give it any **modifier** (considered "Package access" level).

Here is an example:

```java
package this.silly.package;

public class Foo() {
    void thisAction() {
        // do stuff...
    }

    private void somethingElse() {
        // Do secret stuff.
    }
}
```

```java
package this.silly.package;

public class Bar extends Foo() {

    // This will work 
    // because this class is in the same package as Foo.
    @Override
    void thisAction() {
        // Do something else
    }

    // This will not work
    // because Foo made this method private,
    // so it is only accessible by Foo.
    @Override
    private void somethingElse() {
        // Please don't do secret stuff. You might drive me crazy!
    }
}
```